# Ul tag contenet alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a ul list something like this

0 coffee
      some text
 0 tea
   some text
 0 lemonad
   some text

Here the zeros are the bullet images and not the regular bullets of ul.

My problem is after the rounded circle the word " coffe " is align little down. I need the text "coffe" little upwards from the rounded circle. I try with top:0 , but its not working. Thanks in advance.

I tried the line-height :20px and vertical-align : top but that is not helping out :(

Comment: Are these `0` characters or bullets from an `<ul>` element?

Comment: sorry it is bullets not 0 charcter

Comment: list-style-possition:inside; this term is useful ...!

Comment: text-indent:--- checking this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some CSS.

```
ul li {
   line-height: 2.0em;
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

Or put

```
<li style="line-height: 2.0em; vertical-align:top;">Coffee</li>
```

Comment: Then try adding a CSS reset like the [Eric Meyer Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to the CSS, then re-style all elements the way you want. The above CSS code _should_ work.

Comment: Ok i figured out my problem. Thansk Harti, Hope more help from you.

Answer (score 1):

you can adjust your text with css: 
 `line-height: (the height of li)px` or `vertical-align : top`

Comment: @SRquery give me an jsFiddle exapmle, and I give you a solution